# How to clean MBean context of QuickFIX/J properly?

Tags: quickfixj

I have 2 Java integration tests, each of them creates QuickFIX/J FIX session with the same property file.

When second test is running once I try to start connector QuickFIX/J creates session and tries to register an MBean for it. In both tests sessions have the same name, so ObjectName for MBean is the same for second test and its registration fails.

What is a correct way for QuickFIX/J to unregister/clear MBeans that could be used in tests?

Comment: I htink you are doing something yourself to register the MBeans, right?. As far as I know QFJ does not do it by itself. And doesn't unregistering work like outlined here? https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/jmx.html

Comment: @ChristophJohn I don't do something manually (except configuration of jmx port). In AbstractSocketAcceptor.createSessions() -> SessionConnector.setSessions() -> ConnectorAdmin.registerSessions() bean for session is registered when I just call SessionConnector.start()

Comment: If I follow your link I see that it describes how to register connector itself. But my issue is related to registration of session.

Comment: I don't see that in the code. Which version of QFJ are you using?

Comment: @ChristophJohn It is 2.1.1

Comment: Well that's rather old. Can you try with 2.3.0?

Comment: @ChristophJohn I see the same with 2.3.0. ConnectorAdmin.java:182 calls SessionExporter that calls JmxExporter.registerMbean and it fails with the same error that bean with this session name org.quickfix4j:type=Settings,beginString=FIX4.4,senderCompID=... is already registered. Bean name is created in SessionJMXExporter.register

Comment: Hmm strange. QFJ test suite also runs tests with same CompIDs one after another so either you are doing something differently or I don't understand the problem. Could you share some code of what exactly you are doing in your tests?

Comment: @ChristophJohn thanks for help, but I think I can't share the whole code because it is some internal project etc. What I see is that in JmxExporter REGISTRATION_FAIL_ON_EXISTING value is used, so if it doesnt fail on testusuite it means that it is somehow replaced or something like SessionAdmin.postDeregister is called. Could you please advise, is it possible to configure JmxExporter used in SessionJmxExporter from external code somehow? Or should I call something to de-register sessions and related jmx beans manally?

Comment: Could it be that you are not using plain vanilla QFJ but via Spring Boot Starter or Camel or something like that? Because ConnectorAdmin is only called via ConnectorJmxExporter.register() which you said don't call explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, @ChristophJohn. You were correct - there was some JmxExporter call for connector. I removed it and sessions are now registered now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the call of JmxExporter for connector object. It leads to registration of JMX beans for session later. See Christoph John replies.